# IE Login Automation with VBA failed for microsoft website

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I have the following code, which works fine until it fills in my username and Microsoft Login Website seems to produce weird error and I have no idea how to go forward. See code and picture for better understanding of this issue.

[image]

```
Sub testLogin()
Dim IE, username, url, password

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

username = "myusername@outlook.com"
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
password = "mypassword"

With IE
  .Visible = True
  .Navigate url
  Do While .Busy
    Sleep 100
  Loop
  ' fill in username => this step produce weird input value
  .Document.forms.f1.elements.loginfmt.Value = username
  ' click next
  .Document.forms.f1.elements.idSIButton9.Click
  .Document.forms.f1.elements.passwd.Value = password

End With
'clean up code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should get you there:

```
Sub Log_In()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
        While .readyState < 4:  DoEvents:  Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    html.getElementsByName("loginfmt")(0).innerText = "your_email"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

    html.getElementById("idSIButton9").Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    html.getElementsByName("passwd")(0).innerText = "your_password"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

    html.getElementById("idSIButton9").Click

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. I've succeeded with sendkeys but your solution is better.